# SimpleXMLElement PHP4

Tags: php, simplexml, php4

I know SimpleXMLElement doesn't work in PHP4, but is there a something similar I can replace it with to make the script work with PHP 4?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Ister.org's simplexml44 - PHP4 backport of PHP5 SimpleXML](http://www.ister.org/code/simplexml44/doc.html) might help you...

*Disclaimer : I've never used it at all !*

... But I wish you luck : XML-support is one of the "big stuff" that was added in PHP 5...

There were also some XML-related functions/classes in PHP 4 ; but nothing looking like SimpleXML :-(

For instance :

- [DOM XML (PHP 4)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php)
- and even some [XSLT support (PHP4)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xslt.php)

BTW : you should **really** think about switching to PHP 5 : PHP 4 is not supported anymore, even for security-related bugs !

Did you try your application on a PHP5-enabled server ? If it works, it might allow you to use SimpleXML ;-)

There were some problems switching from PHP 4 to PHP 5 ; but maybe not too many for you application ?

Comment: It does completely work great in php5, but I can't switch to PHP5, 4 is what is on the client's host offers, so I have to work within that.

Comment: Ho... This is really too bad :-( Is there absolutly no way to convince them that, in 2009, one year (in a few days ; see http://www.php.net/archive/2008.php#id2008-08-07-1 ) after the **last** version of PHP 4 ever, it is more than time to stop limiting their client to PHP 4 ? Or maybe it's time for your client to get some kind of real hosting provider ^^

Comment: Time for your client to get a new host.

Answer (score 0):

PHP4 had [DOM XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php) and the event-based [sax parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). Neither are drop-in replacements for SimpleXml and if I remember correctly, neither were standard, meaning that you need them installed/enabled as extensions. The sax parser also exists on PHP5, so if you want your code to be forward compatible, that is probably the safest bet.

Answer (score -1):

PHP5 saw its [first release in 2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), and PHP4 end-of-lifed almost exactly a year ago. It's time to move up... and to switch webhosts if your current one doesn't even offer the option.